# Логика работы логических операторов

Tags: c, алгоритм

Какая логика выполнения логических операций в данном коде.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define PRINT3( x, y, z ) printf( "x = %d\ty = %d\tz = %d\n", x , y, z )

    int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

        int x ,y, z;
        x = y = z = 1;
        ++x || ++y && ++z; PRINT3( x, y, z );

        return 0;
    }
```

Операции `&&, ||, !` я привык видеть в каких либо условиях, после знака присваивания, и из-за этого не как не могу понять как получаются выходные данные, `x = 2`, `y = 1`, `z = 1`.

Comment: Если слева от `||` не ноль, то справа ничего не исполняется. Слева — 2. Вот и всё

Comment: @andreymal Как я понимаю приоретет инкрементирования выше обеих операций || and && так чтобы проверить ++y && ++z не ноль необходимо же вроде сначало ++, что приведёт что y and z будут двойками.  Или я как - то запутался в приорететах?

Comment: `++y && ++z` никто не проверяет, потому что слева уже не ноль и справа проверять нет смысла

Comment: @andreymal Раньше я думал как человек, а теперь придётся как компилятор. Раньше не придавал значения оптимизации компилятом.

Comment: @Astrodynamic: Это не имеет никакого отношения к "оптимизации компилятором". Правая часть оператора `||` в данном случае не вычисляется не потому, что "это не имеет смысла", и не потому, что "компилятор решил соптимизировать", а потому, что стандарт языка С++ однозначно **требует**, чтобы в данном случае эта часть не вычислялась.

Comment: @AnT а стандарт это **требует**, потому что иное поведение не имеет смысла :)

Comment: @andreymal Ну почему же. Выражения в С и С++ вычисляются не только ради результата, но и ради побочных эффектов. Как раз таки время от времени встречаются ситуации, когда сокращенное вычисление мешает, а не помогает, подавляя желаемые побочные эффекты. Разумеется, всегда есть решение, но все же...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычное сокращенное вычисление логического значения.

Если в `A || B` `A` истинно - то `B` незачем вычислять, все ясно итак. Если в `A && B` `A` ложно - то `B` незачем вычислять, все ясно итак.

Приоритеты дают, что

```
++x || ++y && ++z
```

это

```
++x || (++y && ++z)
```

Если `++x` истинно (а оно у вас истинно), остальное считать не надо.

А что оно не спрятано в `if` - так если можно написать

```
if (f(x)) ...
```

то это же не запрещает писать отдельно

```
f(x)
```

Comment: Если не сложно добавьте в ответ информацию о логических операциях, которые называются короткое замыкание. Большинство включая меня делают акцент на таблицу приоритетов,  а о данном понятии и не знают. Так ответ станет полным.

Comment: Это только для логических операторов - `&&` и `||`.

Answer (score -1):

The operators are evaluated using the Polish tree datastructure, as in the diagram, and it's a depth-first evaluation algorithm. Let's give names to the operations: A = ++x B = ++y C = ++z D = B && C E = C || D Evaluation order: A, B, C, D, E. Of course, C has an optimisation and if A is true, then E will be evaluated as true without evaluating B C and D. Similarly, if B is false, then C won't be evaluated to optimize the evaluation speed. [Ссылка на источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700352/why-does-x-y-z-calculate-x-first-even-though-operator-ha)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это StackOverflow на русском, переведите ответ пожалуйста.